# How to find unique dataframes in a list? R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of dataframes.
I want to keep only the "unique" ones, regarding to their "inside" values.

This means in the list, the dataframes can have the same names.
Just their content is different, and sometimes a duplicate.
I want to throw these duplicates out of the list.
The goal is to have a list at the end which does not contain duplicate dataframes.

Ok so here is an example of what I mean

[image]

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Ok I will edit and add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iris1 <- iris
iris2 <- iris
iris3 <- iris
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars

dflist <- list(iris1,iris2,iris3,mtcars1,mtcars2)

dflist_unique <- unique(dflist) 

length(dflist_unique)

# 2
```

you are looking for `unique()` function. in the example above, I copied 3 iris dataframe and 2 mtcars dataframe in the same list then in the `unique()` function, I assign it into a new list. it contains only unique ones.

Comment: Does this also work, if the list had for instance: list(iris1,iris1,iris2) etc? I mean if the dataframes also sometimes happen to have the same name?

Comment: So, I can be sure that it stays list(iris1,iris1....)  as long as the content of these two elements are not equal? (Just making sure :) )